# jquery can't change ul li style

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists, click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").on('click', 'li', function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#000000');
});
});
</script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li onclick="window.location.href='start.php'">Start</li>
  <li onclick="window.location.href='event.php'">event</li>
  <li onclick="window.location.href='event_list.php'">event list</li>
  <li onclick="window.location.href='black_list.php'">black list</li>
  <li onclick="window.location.href='logout.php'">logout</li>
</ul>
```

Im trying change style for single cliked li element. Have no idea why this can't work. Any ideas?

Comment: works here http://jsfiddle.net/awfw8jck/

Comment: You have onclicks bound to each list item that redirect the user, nullifying the changes in your jQuery.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? right now the functionality is: on click of the li element, the background color changes and the page is redirected to a certain .php.  what is  your desired functionality? because the background color is changing as your code dictates, the redirect is just redirecting to a new page, in which the color changes no longer exist. are you attempting to css the active menu item depending on which page you're on?

Comment: Working after removing redirect Suppose have to delete this events from each li.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to change the background color of the active page, but because you're redirecting the user on each click of an `li`, you're losing the styling. Instead you should just create an `active` class and then on each of those pages, manually add the class to the `li` that represents that page.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by j08691, inline javascript is not the best idea.  Try this instead:

javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").on('click', 'li', function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#000000');
        var loc = this.id + '.php';  //or $(this).attr('id') + '.php'; (but slower)
        window.location.href = loc;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li id="start">Start</li>
  <li id="event">event</li>
  <li id="event_list">event list</li>
  <li id='black_list'>black list</li>
  <li id='logout'>logout</li>
</ul>
```

Also note that the CSS changes will not be visible if the page is redirected.  You may wish to to open a new tab for the new page, which would look like this:

```
window.open(loc, '_blank');
```